# Dynamic reference to allow use of two versions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am making a small external tool for Visual Studio that uses the following referenced assembly:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client
```

My tool is built in `Visual Studio 2012`, so it uses the reference of that same version, `11.0.0.0`. When I try to run the same tool in `Visual Studio 2013`, the file is missing because the version has changed in VS2013: `12.0.0.0`.

Note that this happens when only Visual Studio 2013 is installed on the machine.

What I am trying to achieve now, is to have my program use the version that is available on the machine. So if the version 12.0.0.0 is found, use that; and if 11.0.0.0 is found, use that.

After some research I came across [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720133.aspx) which said the following:

> To successfully deploy your .NET Framework application, you must understand how the common language runtime locates and binds to the assemblies that make up your application. By default, the runtime attempts to bind with the exact version of an assembly that the application was built with. **This default behavior can be overridden by configuration file settings**.

This can be achieved by the use of a `dynamic reference`, as explained in that same [topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720133.aspx).

While there is information on how to dynamically load references, I am unsure how to approach this.

Based on this I have some questions:

1. Is there any way for me to add one dynamic reference and have the machine it runs on decide which version it uses?
2. Are there any other ways to achieve the use of two versions where only one may be used on the machine?
3. Would an option be to build the application on a machine with VS2012 AND VS2013, and reference both versions?

**Edit**: Option 3 is not possible because Visual Studio complains about a reference to that component already existing.

**Edit 2**: If I add the reference as follows:
`<Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client" />` 
without the use of Version, Culture, etcetera; I get a compilation error saying there is a conflict between different versions of the same dependent assembly.

**Edit 3:** Setting the referenceversion to non-specific does not work either, as this is a buildsetting and not a runtime setting.

Comment: You need a `<bindingRedirect>` in your .config file that forces your dependency on 11.0.0.0 to be redirected to the 12.0.0.0 version that's actually present on the machine.  Building it with VS2013 is possible by setting the "Specific Version" attribute on the assembly reference to False.  Hopefully the assembly didn't change too much.

Comment: Will this still use version 11.0.0.0 if version 12.0.0.0 is not available?

Comment: No, you redirected it.  The .config entry should only exist on machines that have VS2013.  Largely the point of a configuration file.

Comment: Bummer. My program is being run from a network location and is not distributed amongst developers, so this isn't an option. I did find a dirty work-around which is to place the required dll's inside the same shared folder. A dirty solution but it works for now~ still looking for other solutions though. But I may have to start thinking about distributing with and/or without the config file.